# How to identify first and last element of chain in array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular

Guys, I stacked when was trying to set proper classes to messages in chat.
I have a component with next template:

```
...
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#mes of chatMessages; #index = index;">
        user {{mes.user.id}}:
        <span 
                [class.header-recent]="isRecentHeader(chatMessages, mes, index)"
                [class.is-recent]="isRecent(chatMessages, mes, index)"
                [class.last-recent]="isLastRecent(chatMessages, mes, index)">
            {{mes.text}}
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
...
```

I'm trying to apply three different classes to each of message `.header-recent` should be applied to first message in chain of messages from one user. Class `.is-recent` to messages that was posted by user in less then 60 seconds. And `.is-last-recent` to last message in chain of recent messages. Like on picture.

[image]

Messages array looks like

```
[...
{
    "type": "message",
    "id": "19372",
    "text": "а43а\n",
    "created": 1495026352,
        "user": {
            "id": 2
        }
  },
  {
    "type": "message",
    "id": "19373",
    "text": "safaf",
    "created": 1495026357,
        "user": {
            "id": 1
        }
  },
  {
    "type": "system",
    "id": "19374",
    "text": "SYSTEM MESSAGE",
    "created": 1495027801,
        "user":{
            "id": "SYSTEM"
        }
   }
...]
```

I need to write 3 functions, each determines one class to messages. I have two of them at this moment

```
    isRecentHeader(mess, mes, index){
        let lastMessage;
        if( index == mess.length-1){
            lastMessage = mess[index];
        } else if( index => 0 && index != mess.length-1) {
            lastMessage = mess[index-1];
        }
        return lastMessage && !this.calcRecent(mes, lastMessage) && lastMessage.type != 'system';

    }

    isRecent(mess, mes, index){
        let lastMes = mess[index-1];
        return this.calcRecent(mes, lastMes);
    }

    isLastRecent(mess, mes, index){
        // confuse here
    }

    calcRecent(message, lastMessage){
        const messageDate = moment(message.created * 1000);
        const lastMessageDate = lastMessage ? moment(lastMessage.created *1000) : null;

        return lastMessage && (lastMessage.type != 'system')
        && (message.type != 'system')
        && (lastMessage.user.id == message.user.id)
        && ((messageDate.valueOf() - lastMessageDate.valueOf()) / 1000 <= 60)
    }
```

So function `isRecent()` works fine, `isRecentHeader()` works almost as consider, but applies `.header-recent` class to single message. And not working `isLastRecent()` function.
So my question is, how to modify code in `isRecentHeader()` so that it wouldn't apply class to single message, and what should I do in `isLastRecent()` function. Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/dd-tch/pen/JNaQeB?editors=0010) of my example.

P.S. If my question seems unclear or confusing to you pls let me know and I'll try to edit or clarify everything.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Did you know that since the [**v 2.0.0 Beta 17**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta17-2016-04-28) the *syntax* in `*ngFor` was changed from `#` to `let`?

Comment: @developer033 yes I know it, thank you. But in codepen I had use `#`. In real project I use `let`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my team leader from job, he gave me an answer.
He used the setter and getter to handle incoming messages in component.

```
...
private _messages: any[];
recents = [];

@Input()
set messages(messages: any[]) {
    this._messages = messages;

    this.recents = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        const message = messages[i];
        const nextMessage = i == messages.length - 1 ? null : messages[i + 1];
        const prevMessage = i == 0 ? null : messages[i - 1];

        const isRecentWithNext = this.isRecentMessages(message, nextMessage);
        const isRecentWithPrevious = this.isRecentMessages(message, prevMessage);

        if(!isRecentWithPrevious && isRecentWithNext) {
            this.recents[i] = 'first-recent'
        } else if(isRecentWithPrevious && isRecentWithNext) {
            this.recents[i] = 'recent';
        } else if(isRecentWithPrevious && !isRecentWithNext) {
            this.recents[i] = 'last-recent';
        }
    }
}

get messages() {
    return this._messages;
}

isRecentMessage(index) {
    return this.recents[index] == 'recent' || this.recents[index] == 'last-recent';
}

isRecentMessages(message, message2?) {
    return message && message2
    && message.type!='system' && message2.type != 'system'
    && (message.user.id == message2.user.id)
    && (Math.abs((message.created - message2.created)) <= 60)
}
```

And in template to set classes now following code

```
<li *ngFor="#mes of messages; #index = index;">
    <span [class]="recents[index]>
        {{mes.text}}
    </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it using the basic conditions as below

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#mes of chatMessages; #index = index;">
    user {{mes.user.id}}:
    <span 
            [class.header-recent]="index === 0"
            [class.is-recent]="index > 0 && index < (chatMessages.length + 1)"
            [class.last-recent]="(chatMessages.length) === index+1">
        {{mes.text}}
    </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

**[Updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKmKoZ)**

Comment: I need more complicated condition to achieve my purpose

Comment: what is that complex condition??

Comment: I need to consider type of message object, it's user.id, when message was created...

Comment: what conditions you need when user creates a message based on selected type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use first and last boolen value provided in *ngFor like below and use [ngClass] to set the class based on the value:

`<li *ngFor="#mes of chatMessages; let first = first; let last = last" [ngClass]="{ first: first, last: last }">`

Comment: thats not the problem he is facing. in the whole list he needs to identify first and last message of each user in certain amount of time between messages. this wont help.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your issues:

**Single Message Issue:**

1. In order to not adding class to single message, you need to verify that next message is from the same user id.

**Last Message Issue:**

2. Last message is the same logic of first message, just needs to verify that next message is from different user id.

i just made your code work although some refactoring can be made.

```
isRecentHeader(mess, mes, index){
    let lastMessage;
    let nextMessage;
    if( index == mess.length-1){
        lastMessage = mess[index];
    } else if( index >= 0 && index != mess.length-1) {
        lastMessage = mess[index-1];
        if (index < mess.length-1){
            nextMessage = mess[index+1];
        }
    }

    return lastMessage && nextMessage && mes.user.id==nextMessage.user.id && !this.calcRecent(mes, lastMessage) && lastMessage.type != 'system';
}
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/oriprice/pen/MmzmGx)

Comment: Almost done, but I noticed that some of messages are not marks at all. For instance I've updated my  [pen](http://codepen.io/dd-tch/pen/JNaQeB?editors=0010) first message has no any classes, but next two messages from same user has `is-recent` class. I think it's because of time message was created or?

Comment: First message issue is due to fact that there is no lastMessage in that case it gets index of -1. You need to identify that specific case in your code and handle it correctly.

Comment: Yes, but I decided to change approach and write 1 function instead 3. So at evening I will post my answer. You helped me a lot.